# The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments()

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

*We're beginners at Java so please don't give too advanced answers.*

We're currently working on a school project and we're stuck. The purpose with the code is to add an event to an ArrayList but we keep getting an error every time we use `add`, not just in this part of the code.

Thankful for any answer

/Evangelina

Comment: Where do you define `eventList`?

Comment: You cannot add an `Event` to a `List<String>` that you defined as only holding Strings

Comment: And if `eventList` is `ArrayList<String>` then it isn't going to accept anything but a string. And seeing as you can't extend string, you're going to have to insert a string not an Event.

Comment: Also `for( String eventList : set )` you cannot reuse the name of a list as a string variable, you might want to change it to `eventName` or such.

Comment: @svasa not true: https://ideone.com/0nuY0L `eventList` is defined outside the method, so you can both use that field in the method, and define a variable of the same name. (But can != should).

Answer (score 1):

`eventList` is declared as a `List<String>`, which means you can only add instances of `String` to it.

If you want to store `Events` in your list, you should declare it as a `List<Event>`